# How to achieve F-bounded poly-morphism with a mixin?

Tags: scala, polymorphism, mixins

Suppose I have a mixin trait where I want to define a method whose return type depends on the final type of the object the trait is mixed into...

```
trait MultiUnit extends Quantity {
  this: Order =>

  def split(unmatchedQuantity: Long): (???, ???)

}
```

...for example if I have a case class that mixes in `MultiUnit` I would want the return type to look as follows...

```
case class MultiUnitLimitOrder(price: Double, quantity: Long) extends Order with MultiUnit {

  def split(unmatchedQuantity: Long): (MultiUnitLimitOrder, MultiUnitLimitOrder) = ???

}
```

...I would prefer a solution that uses type members instead of type parameters if possible.

Comment: Regular F-Bound polymorphism would bind you the type of `MultiUnit` as an upper bound. Is that sufficient or are you trying to restrict it to the particular type that mixes in `MultiUnit`?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I think an upper bound would suffice, but I am not entirely sure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use an abstract type member like you suggest above, f bounded is the right way. That type member pattern is useful if you don't know the type of `T` ahead of time, e.g you are computing a type. Shapeless uses that pattern all the time, when you request implicit evidence such as:

```
def test[Computed]()(implicit gen: Generic.Aux[Source, Computed]): Result[Computed] = {}
```

This is used to "transfer" the value of an inner type member inside the `Generic` class to `Computed`, a type parameter above.

In your case, keep it simple unless you absolutely must.

```
trait Order
trait Quantity

trait MultiUnit[T <: MultiUnit[T]] extends Quantity {
  this: Order =>

  def split(unmatchedQuantity: Long): (T, T)
}

case class MultiUnitLimitOrder(price: Double, quantity: Long) 
  extends Order with MultiUnit[MultiUnitLimitOrder] {
    override def split(unmatchedQuantity: Long): (MultiUnitLimitOrder, MultiUnitLimitOrder) = ???
}
```

I also don't see why you need a `self-type` bound for `this: Order` instead of just plain `with Order`.

Comment: OP says: *"I would prefer a solution that uses type members instead of type parameters if possible."*

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I meant like the OP suggests, don't worry I know you were just giving him what he wanted.

Answer (score 1):

If an upper bound on `MultiUnit` sufficies, you can do:

```
trait Order
trait Quantity

trait MultiUnit extends Quantity {
  this: Order =>
  type T <: MultiUnit

  def split(unmatchedQuantity: Long): (T, T)
}

case class MultiUnitLimitOrder(price: Double, quantity: Long) 
  extends Order with MultiUnit {
    override type T = MultiUnitLimitOrder
    override def split(unmatchedQuantity: Long): (MultiUnitLimitOrder, MultiUnitLimitOrder) = ???
}
```

Comment: if an upper bound does not suffice is there an alternative or not?